# Property 'sensor' does not exist on type 'Measurement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an simple app which should request measurements from an json-server and show them in a table.
At the top, their should be a select input to select a specific sensor extracted from a list of measurements.

```
export interface Measurement {
    id: number;
    sensor: string;
    location: string;
    time: string;
    value: number;
}
```

To extract the sensors I used a service.

```
constructor(private measurementService: MeasurementService) { 
    this.sensors$ = this.measurementService.measurements$.pipe(
      tap(x=> console.log('SensorService',x)),
      map(ms=> this.extractSensors(ms))
    );
  }
  extractSensors(measurements: Measurement[]): Sensor[]{
    var maxId = 0;
    const sensors: Sensor[] = [ {id:1, location:'abc', sensor: 'sensor'}];
    console.log('extract Sensors',measurements);
    measurements.forEach((m: Measurement) => 
      {
        console.log(m.location,m.sensor);//27
        if(sensors.findIndex(s => s.location==m.location &&s.sensor==m.sensor)<0){//28
          sensors.push({id: maxId++, location: m.location, sensor: m.sensor});//29
        }
      }
    );
    return sensors;
  }
```

Here is the code from my measurment.service

```
private measurementsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Measurement[]>([]);
measurements$ = this.measurementsSubject.asObservable();
```

but now I always get the following errors:

> > ERROR in src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(27,23): error TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
>
> ```
> src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(27,34): error TS2339: Property 'sensor' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
> src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(28,49): error TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
> src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(28,73): error TS2339: Property 'sensor' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
> src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(29,50): error TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
> src/app/_services/sensor.service.ts(29,70): error TS2339: Property 'sensor' does not exist on type 'Measurement'.
> ```

I searched around and found questions but nothing fully matched my problem.
Does anyone know the solution for this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to recreate this in stackblitz

Comment: It seems that there was an error inside the Html which caused the error